# SQL syntax error with "WITH" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, with-statement, where-in

Got a strange problem using WITH alias in a WHERE clause.
Problem SQL statement:

```
WITH CROOM AS (SELECT id FROM classroom WHERE floor = 1)
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id
FROM timetable
WHERE classroom_id IN CROOM;
```

The error is `ORA-00904: "CROOM": invalid identifier`

While both of those semantically similar statements work great.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id
FROM timetable
WHERE classroom_id IN (SELECT id FROM classroom WHERE floor = 1);

WITH CROOM AS (SELECT id FROM classroom WHERE floor = 1)
SELECT DISTINCT T.teacher_id 
FROM timetable T JOIN CROOM ON (T.classroom_id = CROOM.id);
```

Why can't it recognize an alias in WHERE while accepts it in a FROM clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use CROOM as a table. you can write for example:

```
WITH CROOM AS (SELECT id FROM classroom WHERE floor = 1)
SELECT DISTINCT teacher_id
FROM timetable
WHERE classroom_id IN (select id from CROOM);
```